# How to use RxJava for file parsing and SQL generation?

Tags: java, multithreading, system.reactive, rx-java, rx-android

Most examples of RxJava I see have to do with network calls. I am new to the framework, so I am wondering if using it for something like parallel file parsing makes sense as well. I have a directory of files, whose data I need to parse into SQL tables. **Can I do this with RxJava?** I would like it to be as multithreaded as possible for efficiency.

*Description of Data*

My data has a hierarchal structure that starts with a bunch of **Sections**. Each **Section** contains one or more **Subsection**. Each **Subsection** contains one or more **HTML** files.

*SQL Tables*

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM sections;
_id         ordinal     title     
----------  ----------  ----------
1           1           Management
2           2           Emergency Preparedness
```

-- *has a foreign key that references the sections table*

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM subsections;
_id         ordinal     chapter_id  title     
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1           A           1           General   
2           B           1           Resources
```

-- *has foreign keys that references both the sections and subsections table*

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM html;
_id         chapter_id  subsection_id   number      html_filename             
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  --------------
1           1           1           1           /1a-1.html
2           1           1           2           /1a-2.html
3           1           1           3           /1a-3.html
4           1           1           4           /1a-4.html
5           1           2           1           /1b-1.html
6           2           2           1           /2a-1.html
7           2           2           2           /2a-2.html
8           2           2           1           /2b-1.html
```

The **_id** field is a auto incrementing primary key (this will not match the ordinal every time). The **subsections** table is dependent on receiving the primary key for its relevant section. Meaning once **Section 1** has been inserted, Sections **1a**, **1b**, **1c**, etc can be inserted (but not **2a**)

*Directory Structure*

```
      //Section 1
/1.title
      //Subsection A
/1a.title
      //html files for 1a
/1a-1.html
/1a-2.html
      //Subsection B
/1b.title
      //html files for 1b
/1b-1.html
/1b-2.html
      //Section 2
/2.title
/2a.title
      //..etc
```

Each SQL insert can be built with a java builder class, which for **/1b-2.html** would look like this

```
db.insert(HTML_TABLE, null, new HTML.Builder()
                .chapterId(section1)
                .letterId(subsectionB)
                .number(2)
                .build());
```

I will end up having about 50-60 sections, but each SQL insert of a whole section, its subsections, and their HTML files can be inserted in parallel. Does using RxJava make sense for something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rx (on any platform) is not well suited for most forms of parallel processing. It deals with streams, which are inherently serialized. It sounds like you are looking for some kind of ETL tool.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on the best way to do this? Currently I can do this in a giant for each loop, but it's single threaded (boo :( ).

Comment: Lots if you want to use .NET, not so much for Java I am afraid... :(